# target first submenu of parent ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I need to target css for the first level ul submenu in a parent ul.

CSS:

```
#menu li:hover > ul.sub_menu { ...some styles }
```

..but this will ofcourse do it for all the sub_menu's, I only want this particular style for the first sub_menu relative to the parent when you hover over the parent list item.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 
      <ul class="sub_menu"><!-- target only this one -->
       <li>Item
         <ul class="sub_menu">etc...</ul><!-- do not do for this one and so on-->
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 
      <ul class="sub_menu"><!-- target only this one -->
       <li>Item
         <ul class="sub_menu">etc...</ul><!-- do not do for this one and so on-->
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any feedback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:first-child` selector:

```
#menu > li:first-child > ul.sub_menu {
    color: red;
}
```

And then use the descendant selector to revert the changes for the other elements:

```
#menu > li:first-child > ul.sub_menu ul {
    color: black;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4Sb/**

Comment: I can't use first-child because the sub_menu style should be triggered on hover of any parent list item.

Comment: i have tried a similar method to yours. one with #menu li:hover > ul.sub_menu {...to target the first sub-menu} and #menu li:hover > ul.sub_menu ul {...to override previous and target all other sub menus }. but now when i hover all the child items stay open, due to the first css style.

Comment: i just need to target style for the first submenu when you hover over ANY of the parent list items. the reason is i have a separate styling for the parent (top-level menu) and only the first child menu is displayed differently relative to this parent. all the other child menus from the first child menu are the same.

Comment: Then apply the `:hover` selector to your `#menu` element. You can't really work backwards up the tree in CSS.

Comment: I'm not working backwards up the tree. I guess I will have to just simplify it to work evenly accross all sub-menus for now.